# Date issue while downloading CSV format

Tags: php, mysql, csv, date

I have data table reports in my admin section. The three formats in which reports can be downloaded are `Excel`, `CSV` and `PDF`. Two of my options i.e. Excel and PDF are working fine. I am having trouble with CSV format. Problem is the date column for which the values showing are `########` . May I know what could be the possible reason for it.

My code for retrieving date is

```
<td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($lastlogindate)) ; ?></td>.
```

Any insight on this will be very helpful.

Comment: What makes this a down-voted question?? Please explain.

Comment: How do you view your CSV file?  If you view it in Excel, `######` indicates that the value is too long to fit in the cell, just stretch the cell width.  If you see `#####` in a text editor, then it's your code that does not output the proper date.

Comment: Thanks. Stretching made it go. Keep up the good work :)

Comment: np, I made it an answer, thanks for accepting it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you view your CSV file? If you view it in Excel, ###### indicates that the value is too long to fit in the cell, just stretch the cell width. If you see ##### in a text editor, then it's your code that does not output the proper date.

Comment: Wow, read the comments on the question, the OP already said it was the problem, thus the answerm